# Confusion Between Tensorflow Operations and Python Operations

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've checked some related post [Tensorflow vs Numpy math functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410644/tensorflow-vs-numpy-math-functions), but still have some confusion: when shall we use tensorflow library function, and when shall we use python library function? Both are often mixed in the code as shown below.

For example, why shall we use `tf.math.pow` instead of python library `math.pow`? Both variables `warmup_percent_done` and `self.power` are scalars instead of tensorflow tensors.

```
tf.math.pow(warmup_percent_done, self.power)
```

Also, the `global_step_float / warmup_steps_float` actually overloads the `tf.math.divide` operations?

source code link: https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/blob/master/TensorFlow2/LanguageModeling/BERT/optimization.py#L52

```
  def __call__(self, step):
    with tf.name_scope(self.name or 'WarmUp') as name:
      # Implements polynomial warmup. i.e., if global_step < warmup_steps, the
      # learning rate will be `global_step/num_warmup_steps * init_lr`.
      global_step_float = tf.cast(step, tf.float32)
      warmup_steps_float = tf.cast(self.warmup_steps, tf.float32)
      warmup_percent_done = global_step_float / warmup_steps_float
      warmup_learning_rate = (
          self.initial_learning_rate *
          tf.math.pow(warmup_percent_done, self.power))
      return tf.cond(global_step_float < warmup_steps_float,
                     lambda: warmup_learning_rate,
                     lambda: self.decay_schedule_fn(step),
                     name=name)
```

## Update:

So, `warmup_learning_rate` must be a tensorflow tensor object so that the `__call__`function can return tensor object. Two more questions:

1. when calculating `warmup_learning_rate`, why don't we cast `self.initial_learning_rate` to tensorflow tensor objects?
2. Why shall we cast this into tensorflow tensor objects?

`global_step_float = tf.cast(step, tf.float32) warmup_steps_float = tf.cast(self.warmup_steps, tf.float32)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow operations are on tensor objects, as numpy operations are on arrays.

Try to think about the difference between these implementations of the same function.

```py
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+math.exp(-x))

def sigmoidnp(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

and try to call them on `x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])`. what do you expect?

The same holds for tf operations. They act on and return `TensorFlow` objects.

In the example, you are posting,

```py
...
global_step_float = tf.cast(step, tf.float32)
warmup_steps_float = tf.cast(self.warmup_steps, tf.float32)
warmup_percent_done = global_step_float / warmup_steps_float
...
```

the variables `global_step_float` and `warmup_steps_float` are cast as tensor, hence, the `/` operation is actually equivalent to `tf.math.divide` in the exact same way as if you sum two lists

```py
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]

l = l1+l2
```

`+` is equivalent to `l1.__add__(l2)`

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Would you please check the Update section?

Comment: It is the usual Python casting: 1+1.0 will give you a float

Comment: thanks. could you please help with those 2 questions in the Update section?

Comment: I am going to answer, however, I would suggest you to open a new thread since you are in a gray area of the StackOverflow rules https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer.

1. you do, as I said in my previous comment.
2. because otherwise you do not have the result of the division stored as a tensor (hence other tf operations wouldn't be allowed).

Comment: Thanks. For the first question, there is no explicit conversion of `self.initial_learning_rate`  from python datatype to TF tensor. Or are you talking about implicit conversion when multiplying `self.initial_learning_rate`  with a tensor?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about implicit conversion, as when you sum an integer and a float.